# Why I cannot extend a scipy rv_discrete class successfully?

Tags: scipy

I'm trying to extend the rv_discrete scipy class, as it is supposed to work in every case while extending a class.

I just want to add a couple of instance attributes.

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete

class Distribution(rv_discrete):
  def __init__(self, realization):

      self._realization = realization
      self.num = len(realization)

      #stuff to obtain random alphabet and probabilities from realization

      super().__init__(values=(alphabet,probabilities))
```

This should allow me to do something like this :

```
realization = #some values
dist = Distribution(realization)

print(dist.mean())
```

Instead, I receive this error

```
ValueError: rv_discrete.__init__(..., values != None, ...)
```

If I simply create a new rv_discrete object as in the following line of code

```
dist = rv_discrete(values=(alphabet,probabilities))
```

It works just fine.

Any idea why? Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you add a little more code so that we have a [minimal, complete and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  It is much easier for someone to help you if the problem can be reproduced by simply copying and running the code shown in the question, without having to edit it and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Also, whenever you report a Python error, always include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.